# Qual a utilidade do link "compartilhar" contendo o id do usuário (permalink)?

Tags: suporte, hyperlinks

Qual a utilidade do link *"compartilhar"* contendo o id do usuário (*"permalink curto para esta pergunta"*)?

Em outras palavras, por que [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/251541/357) é melhor que [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/251541/como-utilizar-optional-ofnullable-neste-exemplo), sendo que os dois apontam para o mesmo lugar?

Por que o id do usuário faz parte do link?

Comment: Eu gosto de utilizar este link em comentários, por utilizar menos caracteres.

Comment: @danieltakeshi lembrando que se for do mesmo site pode encurtar mais ainda: Escrevendo apenas `[link](/q/8306/70)` Já resulta em [link](/q/8306/70)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compartilhar a postagem com alguém. Você pode postar onde quiser. E como o site é *gamificado* faz sentido ter uma forma de premiar quem divulga mais as postagens daqui. Eu já [ganhei várias medalhas de bronze](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/59/announcer?userid=101) e [algumas de prata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/60/booster?userid=101), mas nem cheiro de ouro ([teve quem ganhou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist)). Ainda que boa parte dessas o ganho é indevido :D Eu ganhei várias porque alguém postou um *link* meu em algum lugar que tem bom tráfego, então tinha meu id mas não foi eu que compartilhei.

Muita gente não entende a *gamificação* do site, faz parte das regras jogar com os pontos, desde que não faça de forma fraudulenta, então que não liga para os pontos (de verdade, a maioria que discursam sobre isso não abrem mão dos pontos colocando tudo como wiki e dando recompensas do resto se ainda assim entrar algum) não está usando o site corretamente, ainda que o problema disso não seja grande (e se usar em excesso pode ser problema também). Medalhas não tem como abrir mão, mas pode evitar fazer certas coisas que dão medalhas, por exemplo só usar o *link* sem o `id`.

Ainda fica mais curto usar assim, por ser bom para alguns. Mas tirar o *insight* que o URL dá com o título. Poderia ter o `id` no "por extenso" também, né?

Comment: É, poderia. :-)